# C# - comparing two .net dlls using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to compare two identical .net dlls which are located at different locations. Hence, I am loading the dlls using `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(filename)` instead of `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(filename)`.  But the .Net dlls that are to be compared have reference to other assemblies (which are in the same folder as the respective dll).  Loading the dll using `LoadFile(filename)` followed by `GetTypes()` throws an `ReflectionTypeLoadException`. How should I load two identical dlls using reflection so as to get their types & compare?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve by comparing same dlls? Can u not use tools like telerik Just Decompile or IlSpy if you just wanna see what's inside the assemblies?

Comment: I have an assignment to create an application that will compare two different versions of a dll. Hence I need to compare the same dlls (of different version) and find out the changes.

Comment: Perhaps something mono cecil based?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ReflectionOnlyLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0et80c7k.aspx) ot [ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom.aspx) methods

You will also need to handle the [ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.reflectiononlyassemblyresolve.aspx) to tell the framework where to find the dependencies.

Comment: Tried this but facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the `ReflectionTypeLoadException` in order to see the list of types which were loaded correctly.  See the following links for some more detail on this:

- [How do i get a list of classes in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827562/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-classes-in-net)
- [MissingMethodException thrown by GetExportedTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509009/missingmethodexception-thrown-by-getexportedtypes)

If you know where the missing assemblies can be found you can also handle the [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event in order to "help out" with locating and loading the required dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to compare two assemblies, you certainly doesn't need to *load* them. I would suggest a more static approach, based on [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil).

It will allow you to compare modules, types, methods -- even at the instruction level, in a simple manner.

Getting started documentation can be found here :

https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki/HOWTO